# Dual video card, dual monitor setup crashes X on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: nvidia, 13.10, xorg, multiple-monitors, intel

My setup is the following:  Ubuntu 13.10, i7-4770K, nvidia geforce 210.  I have the HDMI port of the Intel chip connected to a 4K monitor (3840x2160) and the dual-link DVI output of the GeForce connected to a 2560x1600 monitor.  By default both displays are recognized and enabled in landscape mode (with some weird mouse flickering), however physically the 2560 monitor is in portrait mode.  When I use the "Screen display" UI or xrandr to rotate the display, X crashes and I'm sent to the login screen.

X log can be found here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6753901/

I'm currently using the nouveau drivers, when I tried to use the proprietary ones I couldn't get the nvidia connected display to be recognized at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think nvidia geforce 210 does not have the bandwidth to support 3840 x 2160. You need a DisplayPort 1.2 capable video card./  see http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_uhd4k_gpus&num=2 for more help

Comment: The 3840x2160 monitor is attached to the onboard intel graphic card (which has a 4k capable hdmi port).  The monitor attached to the 210 is running at 2560x1600, which is within the capabilities of the 210 and it's dual link DVI port.